# JS to populate Bootstrap modal with selected text only seems to work once

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Boostrap to create a modal dialog that allows users to enter comments on a given page. I wanted to expand that to allow me to capture the selected text and add it to the content field in the modal:

```
$( document ).on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
 var selectedText = '';
 var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
 if(selectedText != "") {
   $('#comment_content').val("> " + selectedText);
 }
});
```

`#comment_content` is the id of the input field for the modal form.

This works great the first time the modal is shown, but it fails to work on subsequent uses.

Whenever I click the Comment button with some selected text:

```
%a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm{:id => 'comments_toggle', "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#commentModal"}
  Post a Comment
```

I get the modal back, but the selection isn't applied to the `#comment_content` field.

The other interesting thing, perhaps, is that it won't work on a page reload, either. Until the tab with that page is destroyed, or until I simply go to another page, every click of the button with text selected gives me an empty `#comment_content` field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to embed it into a click function for that button:

```
$( document ).on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
  $('#comments_toggle').click(function(){
   var selectedText = '';
   var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
   if(selectedText != "") {
     $('#comment_content').val("> " + selectedText);
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. It makes sense that it wouldn't, though, doesn't it?  `shown.bs.modal`  is happening before the `.click()` in that function can be looked for/captured, which means the button has already been clicked.